# Vb.net register a CTRL-combo with an asyncstate function

Tags: vb.net, keyboard

I am trying to make a calculator that is fully-controlled with the keypad.

I had some trouble with getting the keystrokes on the keypad registered but eventualy I used a GetAsyncKeystate function

```
Private Sub Timer1_Tick(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Timer1.Tick

    For i = 1 To 255
        result = 0

        result = GetAsyncKeyState(i)

        If result = -32767 Then
            Select Case i
                Case Is = 96
                    Display.Text = Display.Text & "0"
                    ans = ans & "0"
                Case Is = 97
                    Display.Text = Display.Text & "1"
                    ans = ans & "1"
                Case Is = 98
                    Display.Text = Display.Text & "2"
                    ans = ans & "2"
                Case Is = 99
                    Display.Text = Display.Text & "3"
                    ans = ans & "3"
                Case Is = 100
                    Display.Text = Display.Text & "4"
                    ans = ans & "4"
                Case Is = 101
                    Display.Text = Display.Text & "5"
                    ans = ans & "5"
                Case Is = 102
                    Display.Text = Display.Text & "6"
                    ans = ans & "6"
                Case Is = 103
                    Display.Text = Display.Text & "7"
                    ans = ans & "7"
                Case Is = 104
                    Display.Text = Display.Text & "8"
                    ans = ans & "8"
                Case Is = 105
                    Display.Text = Display.Text & "9"
                    ans = ans & "9"
                Case Is = 106
                    Multiply()
                Case Is = 107
                    Add()
                Case Is = 110
                    Display.Text = Display.Text & ","
                    ans = ans & ","
                Case Is = 109
                    Substract()
                Case Is = 111
                    Devide()
                Case Is = 13 And ActionValue <> ""

                    Action()

                    Display.Text = ans2
                    Display.Text = Display.Text & Environment.NewLine

                    ans = ans2
                    ans2 = ""

            End Select

        End If

    Next i

End Sub
```

Now I don't know how I should register a Ctrl-combo (like <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>NUM-LOCK</kbd>)
Btw I'm not used to the GetsAsyncKeyState function

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You first need to check if the CTRL-Key or any other modifier-key like Alt or whatever is pressed at the beginning. (refer to http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd375731%28VS.85%29.aspx for the keycodes). Define variables like

```
Dim isCTRLPressed as Boolean = (GetAsyncKeyState(&HA2) < 0)
```

When processing the actual keys you can then fork the respective action

```
If isCTRLPressed Then
  DoThis()
Else
  DoThat()
End If
```

If you meant something else you might elaborate on your post some more. Your code is also rather inefficient since you forcefully check every keystate on every Tick wether it is actually used or not.

Comment: Yeah thing is I got that from another stackoverflow post... anyway Your code works... In the meantime I had found out the CTRL key overrides the function of the key making it not do anything but wath I need it to do. Bad coding ftw!